# Java getting .setText error in my java code

Tags: java, javafx

Please, I'm new to java and I'm currently following a tutorial on java but am getting an error relating to `setText()` method it's not just working and I can't tell the reason it's not working.

This is the code i tried:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.*;

public class Demo extends Application {

    Button button = new Button();

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        primaryStage.setTitle("This is a title");

        button.setText("This is a button");

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.getChildren().add(button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane,400,400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**This is the error am getting:**

```
Error:(23, 15) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setText(java.lang.String)
  location: variable button of type java.awt.Button
```

Comment: Try to use `button.setLabel("This is a button")` method instead.

Comment: The `awt` classes (you imported) are not compatible with javafx. Remove the 'awt import entry', reimport the javafx equilevant and your code should work.

Comment: @n247s it is possible using `javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode`

Comment: @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam although true, way out of the scope of the question and programmers level of the OP. (as correction I could have said "not directly compatible")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You imported a `java.awt.Button`, while you probably meant to use a `javafx.scene.control.Button`.

Explanation: In Java there can be multiple classes with the same name but in different packages. You need to make sure to use the correct class by choosing the right package during import. In rare cases when you might need both classes at the same time, you can also use the *fully qualified name* of a class in your code, i.e. `new javafx.scene.control.Button()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked I imported the wrong package thanks alot